# regex and preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem with a regular expression.
I'm working with tokens and I have to parse a text like this:

```
Just some random text
#IT=AB|First statement# #xxxx=xxx|First statement|Second statement#
More text
```

I use `preg_replace_callback` since I have to use the first statement or the second one, depending on the first expression is true or not; it's a sort of `IF...ELSE...` statement.

What I expect are 2 elements like this:

```
#IT=AB|First statement# 
#xxxx=xxx|First statement|Second statement#
```

So I can start manipulating them inside my callback function.
I tried with this regex `/#.*#/`, but i get the entire string, it's not parsed into elements.

How can I achieve that? I'm sorry but regex aren't my thing :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quantifier `*` is greedy by default. So a `.*` will match as much as it can and as a result it'll match a `#` as well. To fix this you can make the `*` non-greedy by adding a `?` after it. Now a `.*?` will try to much as little as it can.

```
/#.*?#/
```

or you can look for only non # characters between two #:

```
/#[^#]*#/
```

Comment: it works! thanks a lot. Please, can you explain me where was the error?

Comment: `.*` is [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), matching as much as possible (including any `#`s it finds along the way). `.*?` matches as few characters as possible, `[^#]*` matches any characters except hashes.